# Changing Konsole tab bar colours

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, kde, colors, tabs

Using the doc page [Using Style Sheet for the Tab Bar](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/konsole/tabbarstylsheet.html), I've made a `.css` file to change the background colours of Konsole's tabs depending on which one is selected (the default colours are barely differentiable).

However, when I navigate to *Settings ⇒ Configure Konsole ⇒ TabBar* and go to "Use user-defined stylesheet" to select my file, the browser cannot see it.

Is there another way to select my `.css` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree, the colours are too similar. I hit the same problem as you: it won't find .css files in the file selector for some reason. However, I solved this by checking the "Use user-defined stylesheets" checkbox and then typing in the full path to the stylesheet into the text field.

Comment: There we go! I must have cocked it up when I tried this originally, I'm celebrating by having my tab colours as contrasting and wildly coloured as possible.

Comment: I also forgot to click on the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned in the comments above, I did it in the following way :

- create a css file on my directory profile "/home/mlazo" :

```
mlazo@mlazo-pc:~$ cat /home/mlazo/konsole-tab-color.css
background-color : rgba(25,25,25,0.6);
color: white;
```

- then I set the full path of the file in the following field :

[image]

- finally, the outcomes were :

[image]

Hope my experience would be helpful for someone.

Best regards,